# Anyway To Backup & Restore Windows 7 Service Configurations?

Tags: windows-7, services

I am planning to disable & alter some Windows 7 Services. I want to backup the present service configuration as a safeguard.

Is there a batch file, Visual Basic script, PowerShell script or Utility that can easily backup & restore Windows 7 service configurations?  I am aware of System Image & System Restore Point creation / restore functionality. I am specifically looking for service configuration backup.

Comment: To improve your chances of receiving a useful and accurate answer, you should make sure your question has the following: a clear title; a reasonable explanation of what your question is; add as much detail as you can; any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem. You can find further information on [ask] in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in PowerShell :

```
Get-Service -ComputerName '<computer name>' | Export-Csv -Path 'Services.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

That'll dump a list of services and their state for the target computer.